# Document builder from xml gives error

Tags: java, html, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse a html response which is in xml format.

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(htmlresponse);
        InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new InputStreamReader(in));
        Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(inputSource);   //Error is here
```

However I get an error on line which I have commented on.

```
Error - "the method parse(InputStream) in the type DocumentBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (InputSource)"
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.
For me, problem was due to a bad import of class InputSource.

So, I had imported `jdk.internal.org.xml.sax.InputSource` instead of `org.xml.sax.InputSource`. With `org.xml.sax.InputSource` the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Modified code, Try this

```
    String xml = "<test>this is a test xml</test>";
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
```

Comment: again "The method parse(InputStream) in the type DocumentBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (InputSource)"

Comment: The method parse() can take either InputSource or InputStream as argument in Java7 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html.  Which version of Java are you using ?

Comment: 1.6.0_27. Also while in eclipse when I point to the error for possible solutions it says that "Rename in file"